# how to make a post request inside async function?

Tags: mysql, node.js, botframework

At the end of the waterfall-dialog in "summary" (i.e., the last if statement) i want to automatically make a post request without making an API call in Postman, is eventListener the way? How to include it?

```
async summaryStep(step) {
            if (step.result) {
                // Get the current profile object from user state.
                const userProfile = await this.userProfile.get(step.context, new UserProfile());
                userProfile.name = step.values.name;
                //the same for other step values(email, doctor, date)
                let msg = `you want a date with dr. ${userProfile.doctor} , and your name is ${userProfile.name}.`;
                if (userProfile.date !== -1) {
                    msg += `you have an appointment the:  ${userProfile.date}.`;
                }
                await step.context.sendActivity(msg);
                let msg1 = `"${userProfile.date}"`;
                if (msg1) {
                    let z = JSON.stringify(userProfile.name);
                    //and also the other rows to go in the database(email, doctor, date)
                    var name = JSON.parse(z);
                    //and also the other rows to go in the database(email, doctor, date)
                    //this actually works but only if i use postman 
                    var urlencoded = bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
                    app.post('/id', urlencoded, (req, res) => {
                        app.use(express.json());
                        app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
                        mysqlConnection.query("INSERT INTO users(name, email, doctor, date) VALUES('" + userProfile.name + "','" + userProfile.password + "','" + userProfile.doctor + "','" + userProfile.date + "')", function (err, result, rows) {
                            if (err) throw err;
                            console.log("Yeah! record inserted");
                            console.log(name);
                            res.send(result);
                        });
                    });
                    const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
                    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}..`));
                }

            } else {
                await step.context.sendActivity('Thanks. Your profile will not be kept. Push enter to return Menu');
            }
            return await step.prompt(CONFIRM_PROMPT3, `is that true? ${step.result}`, ['yes', 'no']);
// this if statement should "fire" the post request...
            if (step.result == 'yes') {
                return await step.context.sendActivity(`we will contact you soon ${userProfile.password}.`);
            }
            return await step.endDialog();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: What you have tried so far??

Comment: Sorry, here it is

Comment: So basically you are calling a post API in async function but it not works ? If so , could you pls share the successful call that you did in postman ?

Comment: It works but only if i use postman and send it. My purpose is that at the time of reaching this last function, the post call is automatically generated. Pic is there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding , you want to know how to call an POST API from Azure bot async function. Pls try the code below in your `async summaryStep` function to send the post request based on your requirement.

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

var options = {
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'http://localhost:8080/id',
  body: {
    fieldCount:0,
    affectedRows:1,
    //your other body content here...
  },
  json: true,
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'application/json'  //you can append other headers here 
  }
};

await rp(options)
    .then(function (body) {
        console.log(body)
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err)
    });
}
```

Hope it helps .
A
nd if there is any further concerns or misunderstand , pls feel free to let me know.

Comment: You can also use request-promise-native, which does not depend on Bluebird. That is what I am using in my bots for http calls.

Comment: Hello , may I know is it helpful for you ?

Comment: Hi, the "request-promise" that you indicated works equally but only if I use postman, which is not automatic. And I receive this error: "RequestError: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8080". 
I have updated the code of the question, please check the last comment and tell me if it is possible and in what way I can achieve the post request. And thanks!

Comment: Based on the error seems your service hosted on 8080 port has not been enabled .Btw, there is one thing that I not so clear : Seems your code opened 8080 port and listing it . So is the API which hosted on 8080 port will be started on that period only ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, about your question, yes. It starts listening right on that async "step" function. Oh!  and the issue isn´t solved yet. In school we are preparing for the final exam, have to work later on this bot :(  Any suggestions?...cheers.

Comment: Hi @DynaBlaster , generally , if your bot will call other services , the service should be hosted independently and listen requests from outside all the time, instead of combined with the bot.

Comment: Hi @DynaBlaster , I assume that the reason you get that error is due to you sent the request but the service you called has not been started up . So you should host the service you want to call independently and start it up before you call it .

Comment: Thank you! finally worked, just had to include the promise in the right place and install it too. Best.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to move your `app.post` API endpoint to your `index.js` file where your bot is already running on a server. Simply spin up a new "server" and "port" making the endpoint available. Then, in your `summaryStep` (`axiosStep` in my example), make your API call using Axios, request-promise, or what have you, to post your data. When the API is hit, the data will be passed in and processed.

In the code below, when the API is hit the passed in data is used in a `sendActivity` posted back to the bot. In your case, your passed in data would be used for the database call in which you could use the returned response in the `sendActivity`.

Your code would look something like the following. Please note, the `post` actions are simplified for the sake of the example. You would need to update the post actions to make your mySql queries. This sample also makes use of restify for the server (standard for Bot Framework bots) and uses the same port as the bot, but this can easily be updated to use Express and/or another port.

Hope of help!

**index.js**

```js
[...]

const conversationReferences = {};
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

server.post('/id', async (req, res) => {
  const { conversationID, data, name } = req.body;
  const conversationReference = conversationReferences[ conversationID ];

  await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReference, async turnContext => {
    var reply = `${ data }. Thanks, ${ name }`;

    await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
  });
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end();
});
```

**mainDialog.js**

```js
async axiosStep ( stepContext ) {
  const conversationID = stepContext.context.activity.conversation.id;
  try {
    const response = await axios.post(`http://localhost:3978/id`, {
      data: "Yeah! Record inserted",
      name: "Steve",
      conversationID: conversationID
    })
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  return stepContext.next();
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]